# I am trying to make a simple calculator in JSwing

Tags: java, swing

Hello I am making a Java program which has many programs in it.
One of them is calculator

the problem is that we ever I try to call calculator multiple times it multiplies the number I pressed the button for , Times the of times I opened it.
(first times it is working well and the second time it is showing "11" instead of 1 and third time(444555) if I press 45)
here is the main code of it

```
package us.Spunvice.Gui.Calculator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import us.Spunvice.Gui.MainMenu.Menu;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    public static JButton button1 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button2 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button3 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button4 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button5 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button6 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button7 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button8 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button9 = new JButton();
    public static JButton button0 = new JButton();
    public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 520;
    public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 520;
    public static JButton backButton =    new JButton();
    public static JButton buttonEquals =   new JButton();
    public static JButton buttonAddition =  new JButton();
    public static JButton buttonDivision =   new JButton();
    public static JButton buttonSubtraction = new JButton();
    public static JButton buttonMultiplication = new JButton();
    public static JLabel label = new JLabel();
    public static Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
    
    public static int times = 0;
    
    public Calculator(){
        
        if(Menu.timesOpened == 1) {
            CalculatorDeclaration.firstNumber = 0;
            CalculatorDeclaration.secondNumber = 0;
            CalculatorDeclaration.answers = 0;
            CalculatorDeclaration.thePreviousSign = "";
        }
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setState(Calculator.NORMAL);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        
        label.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 50);
        label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setVisible(true);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBorder(border);
        
        button1.setText("1");
        button1.setBounds(150, 150, 50, 50);
        button1.setFocusable(false);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        
        button2.setText("2");
        button2.setBounds(200, 150, 50, 50);
        button2.setFocusable(false);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        
        button3.setText("3");
        button3.setBounds(250, 150, 50, 50);
        button3.setFocusable(false);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        
        button4.setText("4");
        button4.setBounds(150, 200, 50, 50);
        button4.setFocusable(false);
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        
        button5.setText("5");
        button5.setBounds(200, 200, 50, 50);
        button5.setFocusable(false);
        button5.addActionListener(this);
        
        button6.setText("6");
        button6.setBounds(250, 200, 50, 50);
        button6.setFocusable(false);
        button6.addActionListener(this);
        
        button7.setText("7");
        button7.setBounds(150, 250, 50, 50);
        button7.setFocusable(false);
        button7.addActionListener(this);
        
        button8.setText("8");
        button8.setBounds(200, 250, 50, 50);
        button8.setFocusable(false);
        button8.addActionListener(this);
        
        button9.setText("9");
        button9.setBounds(250, 250, 50, 50);
        button9.setFocusable(false);
        button9.addActionListener(this);
        
        button0.setText("0");
        button0.setBounds(150, 300, 50, 50);
        button0.setFocusable(false);
        button0.addActionListener(this);
        
        buttonEquals.setText("=");
        buttonEquals.setBounds(200, 300, 100, 50);
        buttonEquals.setFocusable(false);
        buttonEquals.addActionListener(this);
        
        buttonAddition.setText("+");
        buttonAddition.setFocusable(false);
        buttonAddition.setBounds(300, 150, 50, 50);
        buttonAddition.addActionListener(this);
        
        buttonDivision.setText("/");
        buttonDivision.setFocusable(false);
        buttonDivision.setBounds(300, 200, 50, 50);
        buttonDivision.addActionListener(this);
        
        buttonSubtraction.setText("-");
        buttonSubtraction.setFocusable(false);
        buttonSubtraction.setBounds(300, 250, 50, 50);
        buttonSubtraction.addActionListener(this);
        
        buttonMultiplication.setText("*");
        buttonMultiplication.setFocusable(false);
        buttonMultiplication.setBounds(300, 300, 50, 50);
        buttonMultiplication.addActionListener(this);
        
        backButton.setText("Back");
        backButton.setFocusable(false);
        backButton.setBounds(200, 400, 100, 50);
        backButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        this.add(button1);
        this.add(button2);
        this.add(button3);
        this.add(button4);
        this.add(button5);
        this.add(button6);
        this.add(button7);
        this.add(button8);
        this.add(button9);
        this.add(button0);
        this.add(backButton);
        this.add(buttonEquals);
        this.add(buttonAddition);
        this.add(buttonSubtraction);
        this.add(buttonMultiplication);
        this.add(buttonDivision);
        this.add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == button1){
            new NumbersPressed(1);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button2){
            new NumbersPressed(2);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button3){
            new NumbersPressed(3);
                        
        }else if(e.getSource() == button4){
            new NumbersPressed(4);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button5){
            new NumbersPressed(5);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button6){
            new NumbersPressed(6);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button7){
            new NumbersPressed(7);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button8){
            new NumbersPressed(8);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button9){
            new NumbersPressed(9);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == button0){
            new NumbersPressed(0);
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonEquals){
            new EqualsToPressed();
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonAddition){
            new AdditionPressed();
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonSubtraction){
            new SubractionPressed();
        
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonMultiplication){
            new MultiplicationPressed();

        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonDivision){
            new DivisionPressed();
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == backButton) {
            new BackPressed();
            this.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and the main menu is

```
package us.Spunvice.Gui.MainMenu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import us.Spunvice.Gui.Calculator.Calculator;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static JButton calculatorButton = new JButton();
    public static JLabel calculatorLabel = new JLabel();
    
    public static short timesOpened = 0;

    public static ImageIcon calculatorIcon = new ImageIcon(
             
"C:\\Users\\adminn\\Desktop\\Spunvice\\Spunvice\\src\\us\\Spunvice\\Gui\\Assets\\images\\Cal.png");

    public Menu() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(1000, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        calculatorButton.setText("Calculator");
        calculatorButton.addActionListener(this);
        calculatorButton.setBounds(0, 200, 200, 50);
        calculatorButton.setVisible(true);

        calculatorLabel.setIcon(calculatorIcon);
        calculatorLabel.setBounds(0, -150, 500, 500);
        calculatorLabel.setVisible(true);

        this.add(calculatorButton);
        this.add(calculatorLabel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == calculatorButton) {
            timesOpened += 1 ;
            new Calculator();
        } 
    }

}
```

here is how i add numbers to the label

```
package us.Spunvice.Gui.Calculator;

public class NumbersPressed {
    
    public NumbersPressed(int number){
        if(Calculator.times == 0) {
            CalculatorDeclaration.firstNumber = (CalculatorDeclaration.firstNumber * 10) + number;
            Calculator.label.setText(String.valueOf(CalculatorDeclaration.firstNumber));
        }else {
            CalculatorDeclaration.secondNumber = (CalculatorDeclaration.secondNumber * 10) + number;
            Calculator.label.setText(String.valueOf(CalculatorDeclaration.secondNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

if you want more information here is the repo https://github.com/Dde1ta/Spunvice
Thanks for reading

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What exactly is your question? Also, post the relevant code here, ideally in the format of a [mre]. Furthermore, be sure to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: To rephrase what maloonmeister posted: It is **your job** to reduce the problem to the minimal amount of code needed to demonstrate it. Don't just dump your whole project on us and say "fix it". Questions here must be self-contained (you can link to your repo for further context, but your question must contain the relevant code).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I change it now it might be helpful now for you to understand me problem

Comment: Swing, not JSwing. Also, java packages are typically all lower case.

Comment: Null layouts are not conducive to multiple screen sizes.  Oracle has a rad tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) that will take you through the steps of creating a correct Swing application.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your problem is that you are adding the same `ActionListener` to each `JButton` every time the constructor of class `Calculator` is called and the constructor is called every time the user presses the `calculatorButton` in class `Menu`. This is because the variables are static variables. So the second time you open the calculator, each button has two copies of the same `ActionListener`. When the button is pressed, each `ActionListener` is invoked and hence the number on the pressed button is added to the text of `label` the number of times that the calculator has been opened.

The simplest fix, for the specific problem that you requested help with, is to remove the `ActionListener` when you close the calculator, i.e. when the user presses `backButton` in class `Calculator`. You can do this by changing the `if(e.getSource() == backButton)` block in method `actionPerformed` in class `Calculator`

```java
}else if(e.getSource() == backButton) {
    button1.removeActionListener(this);
    button2.removeActionListener(this);
    button3.removeActionListener(this);
    button4.removeActionListener(this);
    button5.removeActionListener(this);
    button6.removeActionListener(this);
    button7.removeActionListener(this);
    button8.removeActionListener(this);
    button9.removeActionListener(this);
    button0.removeActionListener(this);
    buttonEquals.removeActionListener(this);
    buttonAddition.removeActionListener(this);
    buttonSubtraction.removeActionListener(this);
    buttonMultiplication.removeActionListener(this);
    buttonDivision.removeActionListener(this);
    backButton.removeActionListener(this);
    this.dispose();
}
```

Regardless of the above solution, you really should heed all the advice in the comments to your question. Also note that usually, in *Swing* applications, the variables that are the components in your GUI are declared as instance members of the class and not static members. So, for example, `button1`, in class `Calculator` should be declared as follows:

```java
private JButton button1;
```

Apart from Oracle's [*Swing* tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), there are several books on *Swing* and you may find freely downloadable versions of them.

Also you will find many examples of *Swing* calculators online. Just search for ***java swing calculator*** and see how other people have built a *Swing* calculator.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the initializing of the calculator.
You initialize the buttons only at the beginning of your code, but every time you create a new calculator, you add the action listener to your button, so the buttons call the action listener multiple times.
Your problem have 2 different solutions:

1. Every time you create a new calculator, remove the previous listeners from your button.
2. Create method which called init (or other name that make you sense) which called only one time in your code (maybe in the end of your main method) and add the listeners to the buttons in this function, and not in the Calculator class constructor, and then every button will have only one listener every time your create the calculator.